# Run gvim in terminal

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm on RedHat enteprise at my workstation where both vim and gvim is installed.

when runnint `vim --version` it's clear that i lack a lot of cool stuff (like clipboard capabilities)

When running `gvim --version` it's clear that my gvim version is fully decked out.

I'd like to run vim in the terminal, but I'd also like to use the full capabilities installed with my gvim install. is there a way to run gvim in terminal? something like `gvim --no-window` or the like?

Is there a way to force the `vim` command to use the backend of gvim, while still being in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `gvim` in TUI mode by passing `-v`, but note that you won't have the X clipboard registers unless you're running it under X.

Answer (score 0):

actually `gvim` is `vim -g`

and gvim and vim are in two different conflicting packages on most distros

and for clipboard you need to run `X` (`xorg-server`)

but if you are running terminal (not the virtual console, `tty`) on X, that's ok

take a look at [here](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/vim.1.en)

also you might run `which vim` and `which gvim` to see if pathes differ

for [rhel](/questions/tagged/rhel) do `rpm -qf $(which vim)` (and `gvim`, accordingly) to find out the packages

Comment: They (`vim-enhanced` and `vim-X11`) don't conflict on Fedora and RHEL et alia.

Comment: which `*` returns `usr/bin/*` (star is gvim/vim) `rpm -qf $(which *)` returns `vim-?-7.4.160-2.el7.x86_64` with `?` being `X11`(*=gvim) or `enhanced`(*=vim)

Comment: also `vim -g` doesn't run